# Is there a way to seed 3+ hierarchical levels (One-To-Many) including a self-reference relationship with a JSON?

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api, seeding

I'm building a API and I'd like to be able to seed data from different JSON file each containing a JSON tree. It was working fine until I encounter a "Parent/Children Self-Reference" Relationship.

I created a new .NET Core project to try to make it work in a simple solution with three entities :

```
    public class Library
    {
        public int LibraryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }

    public class Book
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
    }

    public class Chapter
    {
        public int ChapterId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Book Book { get; set; }
        public int BookId { get; set; }

        public int? ParentChapterId { get; set; }
        public Chapter ParentChapter { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Chapter> ChildrenChapters { get; set; }
    }
```

DbContext :

```
public DbSet<Library> Libraries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<Chapter>()
                    .HasMany(p => p.ChildrenChapters)
                    .WithOne(p => p.ParentChapter)
                    .HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentChapterId)
                    .IsRequired(false);

            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
```

Startup.cs :

```
var dataText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Data/JsonSeeding/json.json");
Seeder.SeedFromJson(dataText, app.ApplicationServices);
```

Seeder.cs

```
    public static class Seeder
    {
        public static void SeedFromJson(string jsonData, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            List<Library> collection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Library>>(jsonData);

            using (var serviceScope = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var context = serviceScope
                              .ServiceProvider.GetService<BizDbContext>();
                if (!context.Libraries.Any())
                {
                    context.AddRange(collection);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally, the JSON file :

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Library_1",
    "Books": [
      {
        "Title": "BookTitle1",
        "Chapters": [
          {
            "Title": "Chapter_1",
            "ChildrenChapters": [
              {
                "Title": "Chapter_1_1",
                "ChildrenChapters": [
                  {
                    "Title": "Chapter_1_1_1"
                  },
                  {
                    "Title": "Chapter_1_1_1"
                  },
                  {
                    "Title": "Chapter_1_1_1"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Title": "Chapter_2"
          },
          {
            "Title": "Chapter_3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

It works perfectly when seeding Library>Book>Chapter but it fails when adding ChildrenChapters :

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Chapters_Books_BookId". 
The conflict occurred in database "JSONTreeSeedingTest", table "dbo.Books", column 'BookId'.
```

I understand the error. Is there a way to still use the same format of JSON and defining that items in ChildrenChapters should have the same BookId as the ParentChapter?

Comment: Can you check `collection.First().Book.BookId`? I think those get some other Id than 0 while deserializing

Comment: When deserialiazing, all ids are 0.
But when calling `context.AddRange(collection)` and right before `context.SaveChanges();`, `collection.First().Books.First().BookId` is at -2147482647. And of course, ChildrenChapters have all BookId still at 0. Which trigger the conflict error when calling SaveChanges()

Comment: can you update all Book.BookIds to 0 before calling SaveChanges()?

Comment: So, following your idea, when setting the Books.First().bookId to 0, they end correctly linked in the database. But when I add a new book in the JSON, all the ChildrenChapters are linked to the first book (makes sense).

Comment: @Gapwe can you please share the latest code which works with parent-child models?